# How to Query if an Account exists by name

Tags: corda

I want to use Accounts in my CorDapp and I would like to check if an account already exists before creating a new one.

How can I query the Vault to see if an account with a specific name exists or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int numberOfResults = getServiceHub().cordaService(KeyManagementBackedAccountService.class)
.accountInfo("USER_NAME").size();
```

Btw, this service `KeyManagementBackedAccountService` has a lot of useful functions; it comes with the `Accounts` library. I recommend exploring it.